# An Open Cover $\mathscr{F}$ of $2\mathbb{N}$ That Has No Finite Subcover

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, compactness

What is an open cover $\mathscr{F}$ for the set $2\mathbb{N}=\{2n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ that has no finite subcover? My initial answer is $\mathscr{F}=\begin{Bmatrix}\pmatrix{-n,5n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\end{Bmatrix}$. Is this good? I don't quite see though why it does or doesn't have a finite subcover.

Comment: Is it because no finite subset of $\mathscr{F}$ can possibly cover $2\mathbb{N}$? If so, how do I *prove* this?

Answer (score 1):

It has no finite subcover.  To see this observe that if $n < m$ then $(-n, 5n) \subseteq (-m, 5m)$.  So if there were integers $n_1, n_1, \ldots, n_m$ such that the open sets $(-n_i, 5n_i)$ form the cover, then they would all be contained in some $(-n_i, 5n_i)$ where $n_i$ is maximal among the various $n$.  But clearly $2\mathbb N$ is not contained in this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your $\mathscr F$ does not have a finite subcover of $2\mathbb{N}$. To see this, suppose that a finite subset $\mathscr G$ of $\mathscr F$ *is* a cover of $2\mathbb{N}$. Now let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be the largest natural number such that $(-n,5n) \in \mathscr G$. Such an $n$ exists, because $\mathscr G$ is finite. Then $\bigcup {\mathscr G} = (-n,5n)$ and hence it does not cover $2\mathbb{N}$.

Note that ${\mathscr F} = \{ (-1, n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ would work just as well.